# Использование двух столбцов в Pandas pivot_table aggfunc

Tags: pandas

Пытаюсь посчитать "меру" на основе значений из двух столбцов датафрейма:

,values = ['Единица', 'StartDate'] ,aggfunc = lambda x: round(x['Единица'].sum() / len(x['StartDate'].unique()), 2)

Но получаю ошибку:

KeyError: 'Единица'

Ругается имеено на aggfunc.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__не картинкой__) и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Датафрейм представляет из себя 3 поля: [Ответственный, Дата активности, Вес активности]. Индексом сводной таблицы выступает Отвественный, в качестве колонок Годы и Месяцы активности. Ожидаю получить среднее значение веса активностей в день на одного ответственного помесячно. Формула расчёта среднего = сумма весов всех активностей / кол-во строк с уникальной датой по  этому ответственному.

Comment: без примера входных и выходных данных вы получите, в лучшем случае, непроверенную идею (наподобие того, что вы указали в вопросе). Если привести примеры входных и выходных данных резко увеличивается вероятность получить работающий и проверенный код. PS советую все-таки прочитать вопрос-ответ по указанной ссылке